# SCIO DataFlow: Error message from worker: java.lang.ClassCastException: class cannot be cast to class org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, avro, spotify-scio

tried with scio 0.12.5 both with beamVersion = "2.45.0" and "2.46.0" and scio scio 0.12.8 (beam "2.46.0") and reading from BigQuery (TypeSafe Annotations https://spotify.github.io/scio//io/BigQuery.html#type-annotations ). Java version 11.0.17 (works fine with DirectRunner in local)

```
object MyApp {
      // reading table
      val table = sc.typedBigQuery[MyTable]()
      table.take(5).debug()

////

  @BigQueryType.fromTable("dataset.myTable")
  class MyTable
```

setting up in SBT -Dbigquery.project=myProject and in args --tempLocation=gs://myTempBucket.

But when running in DataFlow a **java.lang.ClassCastException** is thrown:

```
Error message from worker: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.MyApp$MyTable  cannot be cast to class org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord (com.MyApp$MyTable and org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getField(GenericData.java:697)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getField(GenericData.java:712)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:164)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:156)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:118)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:62)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.avro.coders.AvroCoder.encode(AvroCoder.java:378)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TimestampedValue$TimestampedValueCoder.encode(TimestampedValue.java:110)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TimestampedValue$TimestampedValueCoder.encode(TimestampedValue.java:88)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.IterableLikeCoder.encode(IterableLikeCoder.java:113)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.IterableLikeCoder.encode(IterableLikeCoder.java:59)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.encode(Coder.java:136)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.NullableCoder.encode(NullableCoder.java:73)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.NullableCoder.encode(NullableCoder.java:63)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource$BoundedToUnboundedSourceAdapter$CheckpointCoder.encode(UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource.java:236)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource$BoundedToUnboundedSourceAdapter$CheckpointCoder.encode(UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource.java:215)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.encode(Coder.java:136)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.flushState(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:435)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1406)
```

Other considerations:

1. The app (Streaming) end to end has been tested reading from PubSub, Kafka and sinking in GCS, BigQuery and PubSub but this problem arises just when I start using a new feature to read (as a side input in the future) a Type safe BigQuery Table.
2. The app is launched by a flex template
3. Pulling an image from Docker, deployed by
   `sbt -v -Dsbt.insecureprotocol=true -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.color=false -Dbigquery.project=${PROJECT_ID} clean pack`  and `docker build -t endpoint/app_name:version --build-arg`  , etc

I do not know if it is an issue resolving the schema with macros (they are resolved by the compiler step and I am missing a setup when launching the app?). Besides, *MyApp.MyTable.class* (also tried with MyTable.MyTable.class) is properly generated in `sbt clean pack` step, but it does get the values of **MyTable** as we can see here:

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: value MyTable(E2F3C44E4858A3210A60FC65,999,1,2009-06-08T13:06:44.188829000000,2009-06-08,9999-12-31,ES,19,30,30,4001020147,0,0,0,30,2,0,N,N,N,N,N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,268,0,EUR,N,N,N,0,0,0,900,0,1,0,0,0,00100000VISC,1,0,0,0001-01-01,0,BANK, ,2020-04-28T18:14:33.395Z,PPAE938 ,6009    ,ES,19,0,2023-05-09T09:13:15.960Z,RR,Krtable) (a com.MyApp$MyTable) **cannot be cast to expected type root**
    at org.apache.avro.path.TracingClassCastException.summarize(TracingClassCastException.java:79)
    at org.apache.avro.path.TracingClassCastException.summarize(TracingClassCastException.java:30)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:84)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.encode(AvroCoder.java:373)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TimestampedValue$TimestampedValueCoder.encode(TimestampedValue.java:110)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TimestampedValue$TimestampedValueCoder.encode(TimestampedValue.java:88)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.IterableLikeCoder.encode(IterableLikeCoder.java:113)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.IterableLikeCoder.encode(IterableLikeCoder.java:59)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.encode(Coder.java:136)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.NullableCoder.encode(NullableCoder.java:73)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.NullableCoder.encode(NullableCoder.java:63)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource$BoundedToUnboundedSourceAdapter$CheckpointCoder.encode(UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource.java:236)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource$BoundedToUnboundedSourceAdapter$CheckpointCoder.encode(UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource.java:215)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.encode(Coder.java:136)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.flushState(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:435)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1516)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$800(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:167)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$4.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1139)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.BoundedQueueExecutor.lambda$executeLockHeld$0(BoundedQueueExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S.1:
The interim - temp "myTable.avro" (that SCIO assemblies in GCS when using @BigQueryType.fromTable or similar) looks correct:

```
INFO 2023-05-17T10:31:42.133Z Matched 1 files for pattern gs://my-bucket-staging/temp/BigQueryExtractTemp/4653ca8e8ff9464683ba07414439d81a/000000000000.avro
```

with exactly the same schema generated with both the DirectRunner in local and the DataFlowRunner

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Root",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "bank",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "doc" : "Entity code",
    "default" : null
  }, {

....
```

P.S.2: Versioning workarounds:

- Version of scio and beam were increased with the same result.
- Excluded avro version from other jars (it does use 1.8.2 which is the one linked to the SCIO version)
- sbt.version=1.8.2
- tried also packing java 8 (JAVA_VERSION: 1.8.0_361 / JAVA_VERSION_SEM: 8.0.361) instead of java 11

P.S.3: Same error by doing (works just fine in local):

```
sc.typedBigQuery[MyTableRow](Table.Spec(s"myTable"))

  @BigQueryType.toTable
  case class MyTableRow(
    id: String,
    bank: Long,
```

===> **CODE**: [MinimalPubSubBQLookUp](https://github.com/albertols/scio-db/blob/develop/src/main/scala/com/db/myproject/slack/MinimalPubSubBQLookup.scala#L30) <===

Comment: Beam bug: https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/26329